# MobX reset store to initial state

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I would like to reset the store variables back to initial values once the button is clicked on my modal window, as for now once the button is clicked on if I come back to my modal window the button remain enabled.

Store

```
@observable isValidPassword = true;
@observable isPasswordMatched = false;

@action
setIsValid = isValid => {
    this.isValidPassword = isValid;
};

@action
setIsMatched = isMatched => {
    this.isPasswordMatched = isMatched;
};
```

Comment: I don’t see how this piece of code relate to any button anywhere :-/

Comment: Correct because the question was regarding resetting a state of store variables , I have posted a solution below, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed :

In the component you can call

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.validationPasswordStore.reset();
}
```

In the store you can either call your setters or just assign the default values yourself

```
@action
reset() {
    this.setIsMatched(false);
    this.setIsValid(true);
}


  @action
    reset() {
    this.isValidPassword = true;
    this.isPasswordMatched = false;
}
```